# Input Excel text into fields on HostExplorer mainframe emulator screen

Tags: vba, excel, terminal-emulator

I'm working with the HostExplorer mainframe terminal emulator. My VBA knowledge is based on piecing together bits of information I've found online to make other macros.

I'm making a macro to enter an invoice into the mainframe, move between a few screens, input information which will generate a link then use that link to save a file to a predetermined folder on my computer.

I'm stuck at the inputting information part. After navigating to the last screen I need to input text into specific fields in the mainframe.

I know how to identify the location on the screen and use that to create variables.

How can I do the reverse, input a string held in a variable (or just a random letter) to a specific location on the screen?

```
Sub MiscFileDownload()

Dim HostExplorer As Object
Dim MyHost As Object
Dim Rc As Integer

On Error GoTo GenericErrorHandler

Set HostExplorer = CreateObject("HostExplorer") ' Initialize HostExplorer Object
Set MyHost = HostExplorer.HostFromProfile("*****") ' Set object for the desired session
If MyHost Is Nothing Then GoTo NoSession

Dim ColALastRow As Long
ColALastRow = Worksheets(1).Columns("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
Dim Pro As String
Dim MiscTest As String
Dim iPSUpdateTimeout

'enter pro then F2 and F9

For i = 2 To ColALastRow

    Pro = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
    Rc = MyHost.Keys(Pro)
    iPSUpdateTimeout = 60
    MyHost.RunCmd ("Enter")
    Rc = MyHost.WaitPSUpdated(iPSUpdateTimeout, True)

    If Rc <> 0 Then GoTo OnWaitPSUpdatedTimeout

    iPSUpdateTimeout = 60
    MyHost.RunCmd ("PF2")
    Rc = MyHost.WaitPSUpdated(iPSUpdateTimeout, True)

    If Rc <> 0 Then GoTo OnWaitPSUpdatedTimeout

    iPSUpdateTimeout = 60
    MyHost.RunCmd ("PF9")
    Rc = MyHost.WaitPSUpdated(iPSUpdateTimeout, True)

    If Rc <> 0 Then GoTo OnWaitPSUpdatedTimeout

    MiscTest = Mid(MyHost.Text, 1466, [3])        

    If MiscTest = "YES" Then 'test for Misc if true move to next screen
        Rc = MyHost.Keys("v")
        Rc = MyHost.WaitPSUpdated(iPSUpdateTimeout, True)

        If Rc <> 0 Then GoTo OnWaitPSUpdatedTimeout

        MyHost.RunCmd ("Tab")
        Rc = MyHost.WaitPSUpdated(iPSUpdateTimeout, True)

        If Rc <> 0 Then GoTo OnWaitPSUpdatedTimeout

        Rc = MyHost.Keys("v")
        Rc = MyHost.WaitPSUpdated(iPSUpdateTimeout, True)

        If Rc <> 0 Then GoTo OnWaitPSUpdatedTimeout

        MyHost.RunCmd ("Tab")
        Rc = MyHost.WaitPSUpdated(iPSUpdateTimeout, True)

        If Rc <> 0 Then GoTo OnWaitPSUpdatedTimeout

    Else

        MyHost.RunCmd ("PF1")
        Rc = MyHost.WaitPSUpdated(iPSUpdateTimeout, True)

        If Rc <> 0 Then GoTo OnWaitPSUpdatedTimeout

        MyHost.RunCmd ("PF1")
        Rc = MyHost.WaitPSUpdated(iPSUpdateTimeout, True)
        If Rc <> 0 Then GoTo OnWaitPSUpdatedTimeout

        GoTo NextIteration
    End If

NextIteration:
Next i

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Do you simply want to input a text ? I am not sure what is ur host, but it looks like you can input using the key() method!! Like: MyHost.Keys("thevalueyouwanttoType")

Comment: MyHost.Keys("thevalueyouwanttoType") works to input the string but i need to know how to enter it to a specific location if that makes sense?

For instance, MiscTest = Mid(MyHost.Text, 1466, [3]) will set that variable equal to the string starting at "location?" 1466 on my hostexplorer. How could i navigate to a specific location before using Myhost.keys?

Comment: http://vbcity.com/forums/t/42741.aspx this may be of some help.

Comment: as will this http://mimage.hummingbird.com/alt_content/binary/pdf/support/nc/automatinghostapplications.pdf  `host.fields(x).text`

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have recorded the above code using Humming Bird Application:

Once you have found the Position in your screen, you can pass the variable to the specific _________________, for eg; `myHost.area(4,2,4,10)` is the position where you want to input something,

`MyHost.Area(4,2,4,10) = "desired_text"`

If you want to find the area in `HostExplorer`,
Goto Immediate Window (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>), type `?MyHost.area(7,2,7,70)` and press enter
=> 2 is the starting position and 70 is the end position.

You will get the text or values present in 7th row from 2nd character to 70th character.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, put a watch on myHost and check the .item.fields proriety.
That way you will find out the item number of each field.
Then you can input using this item.

I dont have the code in front of me but it goes something like
MyHost.fields.item(78)= yourVariable or "30s" as exemple.